# How to change main menu in woocommerce product detail page globaly for all products

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, woocommerce

How can I change, in Woocommerce, globaly for all products detail, items in main menu? I have created menu "Eshop menu" but it can be set in each product separately and i have hundreds of products.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: what will be on the menu ? will that menu be dynamic or a static one... say like menu 1 for all product page and menu 2 for rest of the site.

Comment: Yes, menu1 for all product detail pages and menu2 for all other pages. Both menu will be static.
But, there is 500 products, so there is not option to set it up manualy, one by one.